# How do I resize colour effect strips in the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I need to be able to resize the effect strip "Colour" in the VSE, which is defaulting to full screen size, and I can find no options to resize it to be smaller and occupy the exact part of the video I need it to occupy. It's all or nothing. I tried looking it up in the Blender manual, at https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/strips/effects/color.html, but those instructions were not helpful at all and appear to be wrong. I have no tools to edit the size of my colour strip and I tried using the "crop" tool inside the "edit strip" box, but that did nothing.

So how am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you enable cropping, enable "Image Offset" as well.

[image]

I also recommend you check out the [VSE_Transform_Tools Addon](https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools) which makes this kind of thing a piece of cake.

Comment: "When you enable cropping, enable "Image Offset" as well." - I tried that and it doesn't work. It always crops from the right, regardless of whether I set a "Left" or "Right" side crop. I also can't see the frame in the background to know when I have the crop aligned in the right place and size. I just see the "transparency" BG in the front frame (the colour strip). I checked the link for that addon, but I can't find anywhere to download it, just info on contributors and contributions history.

Comment: When Image Offset is enabled, you'll need to also set the x and y position as well to crop from both directions. I really recommend that addon for this kind of thing.

Comment: OK, thanks, I did manage to find the download link, which was hidden a bit in a long list of other things. I'll try it out next time I have some spare time to work on my video. Thanks.